# ionic 2 angular 2 payment

Tags: angular, ionic2, payment

hi i want internal pay in my app.
in my web site i use

```
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{pasargadModel.clientToken}}" />

    <input type="hidden" name="merchantId" value="{{pasargadModel.merchantId}}" />

    <input type="hidden" name="PaymentId" value="{{pasargadModel.PaymentId}}" />

    <button androidButton class="btn btn-primary nexus" type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
        اتصال به درگاه
    </button>

</form>
```

and worked for my. but in my app not working

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: not show any error. do not react